# apache ignite node crashing due to out of memory while running select query?

Tags: ignite

Apache Ignite node crashing  with out of memoery due to sql query processign large data.

1. anything available in any  version later than 2 of apache ignite to avoid this?
   Is there any configuration to restrict queries to use certain memory quota.

Comment: Hi. Can you provide full stack trace? Do you collect GC logs, was there any GC issues in logs? have you tried following optimization: https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/perf-and-troubleshooting/sql-tuning#lazy-loading?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any configuration to restrict queries to use certain memory quota.

GridGain (based on Apache Ignite) has exactly this - see [the memory quotas docs](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/memory-configuration/memory-quotas).